# Did any Sith switch for the first time to the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, sith

Several Sith, including Tyranus and Vader, were former Jedi who became Sith after a fall/conversion to the Dark Side.

Did any Sith turn to the light side for the first time and become Jedi, *having never previously been a Jedi*? That is, these would be people who had been Sith for all, or most of their life, taking their first steps into the Jedi Order after a fall (or, if you will, a "rise") to the Light Side.

Darth Vader/Anakin's return to the Light Side does not count because he had been a Jedi first before he became a Sith - his conversion to the light side was a reversion to his former status.